# What is correct annotation for multidimensional array in JPA Entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the right annotation for Entity field that maps to data of text[] type in postgres?

In Postgres db table I have a column that type is text[]. Where I store a data like:
{{00:00:05,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{00:00:10,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}

My Entity Class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "spiroergometry")
public class Spiroergonometry {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name="first_name")
  private String firstName;
  @Column(name="last_name")
  private String lastName;
  @Column(name="height")
  private double height;
  @Column(name="weight")
  private double weight;
  @Column(name="t_start")
  private Date tStart;
  @Column(name="t_end")
  private Date tEnd;
  @Column(name="temperature")
  private double temperature;
  @Column(name="protocol")
  private String  protocol;
  @Column(name="bd_date")
  private Date bdDate;

  @?????????
  private List<SpiroRawData> rawData;




class SpiroRawData {
    private String time;
    private String wr;
    private double vo2STPD;
    private double vo2;
    private double co2STPD;
    private double veBTPS;
    private double rer;
    private String wrTM;
    private double chD;
    private double veVO2;
    private double veVCO2;
    private String v;
    private double cho;
    private double fat;
    private double petO2;
    private double petCO2;
    private double sv;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map your `List<SpiroRawData>` to `text[]` because `SpiroRawData` is a type with its own properties.

You can use `@ElementCollection` instead to make JPA map it to a separate table.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "spiroergonometry_id"))
private List<SpiroRawData> rawData;
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class SpiroRawData {...}
```

Comment: Do I have to use join here? Cause all data is stored in one table.

Comment: @user3693537 If in any way possible, move all the data from `SpiroRawData` into a separate table. I think that you would need a custom column transformer in your current setup

Comment: No, there is no way to move it. What is annotation to map multidimensional array?